# Number of subgroups of order $14$ in $\Bbb Z_{70} \times\Bbb Z_{98}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to find the number of subgroups of order $14$ in $\Bbb Z_{70} \times \Bbb Z_{98}$.

I can find the number of elements of order $14$. I can then find the number of cyclic subgroups by dividing the number of elements of order $14$ by $6$.

How can I find the number of non-cyclic groups?

Comment: Hint: Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of non-cyclic such subgroups is $0$: an abelian group of order $14$ is cyclic (by the structure theorem, CRT or some other simple arguments).

An element $(a,b)$ has order $\rm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.  So we get the possibilities $(2,7),(7,2),(2,14),(14,2),(7,14),(14,7),(1,14),(14,1)$ and $(14,14)$.  Note that in a cyclic group there are $\varphi(2)=1, \varphi(7)=6$ and $\varphi(14)=6$ elements of order $2,7$ and $14$ respectively.

Thus we get $6+6+6+6+36+36+6+6+36=144$.  But to finish we need to divide by $\varphi(14)=6$, since there are that many elements  of order $14$ in each such subgroup.  Thus we get $24$.

Comment: Are you assuming that all subgroups are of the form $H \times K$?

Comment: No, all I basically did was count the number of elements of order $14$.  Using that the order of $(a,b)$ is $\rm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

Comment: So did you consider the possibility that both $a$ and $b$ have order $14$, for example?

Comment: You're right, I forgot that.  So there must be $15$.

Comment: There are many others also, right? $(7, 14)$, $(14, 7)$, et cetera. Also, there are multiple elements of order $14$ in each group.

Comment: You're right.  I've blown it.  Let me re-do.

Comment: The possibility $(14, 14)$ seems to be missing again.

Comment: Thanks for the touch up.  @AryamanMaithani